# Javascript confusion with before() and after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project and I use the before() and after() javascript methods. I use it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">    
    <div><div class="main" style="display:block;">Page 1 odd</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 2 even</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 3 odd</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 4 even</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 5 odd</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 6 even</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 7 odd</div></div>
    <div><div class="main" style="display:none;">Page 8 even</div></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.main:odd').before("<div class='left'></div>");
});

$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.main:even').after("<div class='right'></div>");
});
</script>
```

So this will create in odd divs before the class .main the new div element called .left and the same for the other. The thing is that this is working until Page 6, after that it will not create another element. Think the html code and the idea like a book when the website opens it shows Page 1, when the user hit next button shows Page 2 and Page 3 and so on. If anyone knows why this happened. Thanks in advance. Sorry but I am a new in javascript.

Comment: Well, it works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/DP2mY/

Comment: Works for me... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zcGeK

Comment: unless the elements after page6 are not created dynamically it should be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7QpZu/1/

Comment: this is just a sample of code not the real code.. maybe is something wrong with some other code in my script...thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem about. It was so simple, I had to move my code above another code in my file to work! Thank you for your help!